# AutoScale Label Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, font-size, autosize, stacklayout

I am working on an app that displays results from a RSS feed. I am trying to show the Title and the Date in the same row of a Stacklayout.

**Xaml Code:**

```
StackLayout>
    <Label Text="60 Second Sports" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <ListView x:Name="mainArticleRssList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="ListItems_Refreshing" ItemTapped="RssList_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="15,0,15,0">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                               MaxLines="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" 
                               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                               MaxLines="1"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <controls:AdMobView />
</StackLayout>
```

**Here is what it looks like:**
[image]

**What I Expect:**

I want the Title to auto scale  to fit in the same row as the date. Is it possible to set a width for the entire row and then have the two labels fit inside of the row?

**Other fruits of a few hours of googling:**

Here are some of the links I found, but some are old and not sure if they work.
This one is old [Auto Scale Text Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713669/auto-scale-text-size)

This one didn't work [Auto-scaling label fontsize in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117979/auto-scaling-label-fontsize-in-xamarin)

I also found a couple Nuget packages, but i don't think i need to do that.
https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43468/autosize-font-label

Comment: Hello.  Author of Forms9Patch here.  This is exactly why Forms9Patch.Label element was written.  Autosizing is something that doesn't work as well as it should on most platforms - even iOS falls short in some regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid Layout inside stack layout to achive it

```
<ListView x:Name="mainArticleRssList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True" Refreshing="ListItems_Refreshing" ItemTapped="RssList_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="15,0,15,0">
                     <Grid x:Name="grd">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                               MaxLines="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" Grid.Column="1"
                               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                               MaxLines="1"/>
                </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Use this code and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your needs like this screenshot?

[image]

You can use `Grid` to achieved that.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Xamarin.Forms native cell" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
           <ListView x:Name="listView" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
        ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           MaxLines="2" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           MaxLines="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>


                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

If title is too long, you can set`LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"` it will automatically truncate when the label reaches the end of the container.

Comment: Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.