# Label TextProperty CoerceValue delegate not called

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use `Reflection` to set the `Label.TextProperty.CoerceValue` to my custom delegate (`TextProperty.CoerceValue` are null by default)
but when Label text changed, the delegate are not called

the same strategy are apply/tried on `Image.SourceProperty`, `Entry.TextProperty`
all are called successful

is bug or `Label.TextProperty` by design will not call CoerceValue delegate?

thank you very much.

**Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.947036**

```cs
var property = Label.TextProperty;
var coerceValue = property.GetType().GetProperty("CoerceValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
oldDelegate = coerceValue?.GetValue(property) as BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate;
coerceValue?.SetValue(property, (bindable, value) => {
    var modified = ModifyValue(value); // simply modify the value if required
    return modified
});
```

Comment: instead of describing what you're doing, please show us the code

Comment: hi Jason, the code is quite straight forward, just set custom delegate to apply some logic and return new value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call CoerceValue when Label.Text changed, I suggest you can use Bindable Properties to bind Label.TextPrperty.

```
public partial class Page9 : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty labelvalueProperty = BindableProperty.Create("labelvalue", typeof(string), typeof(Page9), null , coerceValue: CoerceValue);
    public string labelvalue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(labelvalueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(labelvalueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static object CoerceValue(BindableObject bindable, object value)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        if(str=="cherry")
        {
            str = "hello world!";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public Page9 ()
    {         
        InitializeComponent ();
        label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "labelvalue");

        labelvalue = "this is test";
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelvalue = "cherry";
    }
}
```

You can see the CoerceValue can be fired when Label.Text property changed.

Comment: hi @cherry thanks for the idea, but with this solution, i have to create thousands BindableProperty for all my labels

Comment: @codetale, For label, it don't have TextChanged event, so you don't have any event to handle somethong when text changed, like entry. If you don't want to create bindableproperty, I suggest you can use bind like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595801/handle-event-when-label-text-change, I am not sure it is bug or others, so you can create one thread at github for better help.

Comment: actually i'm not try to track the text changed event, i try to validate and change the value when text is about to update, thats why the `CoerceValue` are handy

Comment: @codetale, Now, have you solved your issue now? If yes, please share your solution here and mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Page **Page1** in a **Xamarin.Forms** Project, with the following simple code in the ***code behind***:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{

    Label l = new Label();

    BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate d = (s, a) => 
    {
        string modified = "textY"; // simply modify the value if required
        return modified;
    };
    var property = Label.TextProperty;
    var coerceValue = property.GetType().GetProperty("CoerceValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var oldDelegate = coerceValue?.GetValue(property) as BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate;
    coerceValue?.SetValue(property, d);


    l.Text = "1"; // Text property is set to textY thanks to CoerceValueDelegate!


    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

when i call `l.Text = "1"` the **BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate** i defined is correctly called, and `l.Text` is set to `textY` as expected.

@codetale, are you able to run this code on your side?

Comment: Hi @Julipan,
weird, I found that if defined:  
* at `App.OnStart`, it wouldnt work  
* at first page `OnAppearing` its working  
* at `App.OnStart` wrap with BeginInvokeOnMainThread, its working

Comment: @codetale, i just copy-pasted the SetValue code in my Answer to App.OnStart, and it is correctly working. After i set the value of my label, the CoerceValueDelegate is called. I am using X.F. 4.3. If you use the code as in my Answer in the App.OnStart (without BeginInvokeOnMainThread), is the CoerceValueDelegate not being called?

Comment: yes i am using your code in App.OnStart, but have to wrap ```coerceValue?.SetValue(property, d);``` in BeginInvokeOnMainThread to have the delegate get called. no idea why...

Comment: hi @Julipan, i found that if you remove ```Label l = new Label();l.Text = "1";``` from your code but put in on XAML and set `MainPage` to this XAML after the delegate are set. Then the `CoerceValueDelegate` will not called unless wrap ```coerceValue?.SetValue(property, d);``` in BeginInvokeOnMainThread